# Не создается проект Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Привет.

Установил Python 3, виртуальное окружение и Django 2 в нем.
Активировав окружение, пытаюсь создать проект django командой django-admin startproject project_name,- получаю ошибку Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
Пробую создать так: django-admin.py startproject project_name,- ошибка Unable to create process using.

Почему не получается создать проект?

Comment: а какой командой вы создавали виртуальное окружение?

Comment: Так python3 -m venv D:\My-env

Comment: можно попробовать обновить пип `python -m pip install -U pip`

Answer (score -1):

После активизации вирт.среды, устанавливаем саму Django : pip install Django, а затем создаём проект. В Django 2.0, Python 3.4 и выше, команда: django-admin startproject mysite
Может здесь есть решение вашего вопроса: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin

Comment: я так и сделал. Создать проект пытаюсь в активированном виртуальном окружении командой django-admin.py startproject project_name - ошибка